# Extract certain character set from cell Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm using IFTTT to keep track of my PayPayl invoices. Every time I get a new invoice email, a row is added to my Google Sheet. However, the entire message appears in one cell of my sheet.

Is there a way to extract the Transaction ID and put it in a seperate cell? I have tried using =SPLIT, but no luck so far.

Here a link to an example: https://goo.gl/w3oA9R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left you an example on your sheet highlighted in green  - the formula in case anyone else is wondering is this:

```
=regexextract(concatenate(D2);".*(Transaction ID:.*)")
```

note: if you want the id by itself, then modify it slightly like this:

```
=regexextract(concatenate(D2);".*Transaction ID:(.*)")
```