# Need to extract certain data from paragraph listed in Google sheet cells

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I import data from a bot at my work this data is stored like

Time: 6/17/2019 Users: Tom, Gerry, Lisa Cover: 150

Actually, developers here are lazy to give me the data in a proper way so I have to filter it and provide the management with some clean data.

So I take a copy from the bot and paste it in google sheet as one paragraph in one cell, now I want to extract this data independently so I can use it later.

I tried using `regextract` and many other formulas and I failed successfully!

The only good solution was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803617/extract-certain-character-set-from-cell-google-sheets)

But the problem is that the data have to be on a new line not all in one line as my case.

I appreciate your help so much

Comment: Provide screenshot of your data or share your sheet.

Comment: _so I have to filter it and provide the management with some clean data._ You gave some sample data (though the actual spreadsheet, or a version of it, would be better); but anyway please edit your question to show what the converted/filtered/clean data output looks like. _But the problem is that the data have to be on a new line not all in one line as my case._ Would you explain what this means, please.

Comment: Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KJNyJsu8Uw4xuN9mExs8hKLJ63RtrBeKyN8zUFjd2oI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you Tedinoz for help, i ll edit the question

Comment: Actually, I'm nub here, I cant add pictures properly :(

Comment: can you add example of desired output?

Comment: @player0 I add it to the sheet, any output to extract them will be fine and save my life. thank you so much for taking care of my issue.

Comment: @player0 is it possible that the output be put on rows not columns? so sorry for the many requests.

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM({
 REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "(Product Queue:)(.*) Cur"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "(Current online rooms:)(.*) Tim"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "(Time:)(.*) Tas"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "(Task by:)(.*) Num"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "(Number of products caught:)(.*)")}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM({
 REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "(Product Queue:)(.*) Cur");
 REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "(Current online rooms:)(.*) Tim");
 REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "(Time:)(.*) Tas");
 REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "(Task by:)(.*) Num");
 REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "(Number of products caught:)(.*)")}))
```

Comment: Man, you like made a miracle. God bless your kind heart. thank you for your time and effort <3